# Send simple HTML email from command line?

Tags: cron, automation, email

I have a cron job which produces a list of resource, expiration date and the days until expiration. The report produces a CSV file. I attach this to the a message using `mutt -a report.csv`.

I also want to include information in the body of the email. I use gawk to format this into clean lines and add this to the body. It looks something like this:

```
Resource                                 Expiration Date           Days  
======================================== ========================= ========

resource one                             Oct 11 2009 07:59 PM      3    
resource two                             Nov  3 2009 07:59 PM      22     
resource three has a longer name         Nov  6 2009 07:59 PM      28     
rscrc 4                                  Dec  8 2009 07:59 PM      58     
you get the point                        Dec 17 2009 07:59 PM      66     
www.blockbuster1.smartsubs.net           Dec 23 2009 07:59 PM      70
```

*(yes, I fudged the dates and expiration, they don't add up in this example)*

The problem is that most of the recipients do not have their email clients configured to show plain text email using a fixed width font. So, for them, it looks like this:

> Resource                                 Expiration Date           Days
>   ======================================== ========================= ========
>
> resource one                             Oct 11 2009 07:59 PM      3
>   resource two                             Nov  3 2009 07:59 PM      22
>   resource three has a longer name         Nov  6 2009 07:59 PM      28
>   rscrc 4                                  Dec  8 2009 07:59 PM      58
>   you get the point                        Dec 17 2009 07:59 PM      66
>   www.blockbuster1.smartsubs.net           Dec 23 2009 07:59 PM      70

Are there suggestions for how to easily format this text in email so that is forced into a fixed width font? I have flexibility to install new command line tools on this server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently recent version of mutt I believe you can do something like this.

```
mutt -e 'set content_type="text/html"' -a file.csv user@example.org -s "subject" < index.html
```

index.html will be the html body of your message.

Comment: argh - `Error in command line: content_type: unknown variable`

Comment: which version of mutt do you have?  I have mutt 1.5.18 on a Ubuntu.

Comment: I just installed a newer version. It works. Accepted.

Comment: more details: I used that `set content_type` and wrapped my content in `pre` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would say just build an html table using print statements, hacky but works, I have done it before.

Less hacky, would be to use a csv to html table converters.  [Here is one with awk](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3848).  You can then just send both html and plaintext, and their reader should use.  You will have to look up how to do that with whatever mail library/program you are using.

Either way, I would go with the tables over trying to force the fix width font.  I think the table would be more consistent (I don't have any actual evidence of that though).

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to munge the mime-type header (and possibly others)? Or are most email clients helpful about displaying HTML w/o respect to headers.

Comment: Doug: Probably, I don't know very much about that.  You might post that as a specific question on stackoverflow in addition to this post.

Comment: Just tested using `pre` tag and `p style="font-family:courier"` and in both cases the HTML tags showed up as plain text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you wrap the whole thing with a p element and an inline style set for a monospaced font and preformatted spacing?